# Automatically have a shared project update reference based on branch?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We have a shared project that is referenced by multiple solutions. Our problem is that when merge from dev to main or release that shared project reference is still pointing to its dev branch.  We'd like to be able to have it automatically change that reference to match the solution branch.  For example, if we merged the main solution from dev to main the shared project reference would then point to its main branch.  Is there any way to do this automatically?

Our TFS branch setup looks like this.

-Dev

-Main

-Release

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701565/tfs-merging-csproj-files-between-two-branches-that-have-project-references-bet#comment88701225_50701565

Answer (score 1):

Use Relative path reference instead of using absolute path. Edit the .csproj file and change the  elements from absolute paths to relative paths.

Comment: The problem with this is that you can't use relative paths. The relative path to the shared project would need to include the branch (e.g. /projects/shared library/dev/XXX.csproj). This means it wouldn't update from dev to main when moving to the main branch.